# How do I embed a module's UI into a region of an application's shell?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

How do I embed a module's UI into a region of an application's shell?

I have a *Login* module that I want to pull into a region of my Elm application.
However, it's not clear to me on how to accomplish this.

Specifically, how do I bootstrap the *Login* module to render html that a region within my app's shell will expose as UI?

**Login Module:**

```
module Login exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)


-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { username : String, password : String }


model : Model
model =
    Model "" ""


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( model, Cmd.none )



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = UserInput String
    | PasswordInput String
    | SignIn String String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UserInput v ->
            model

        PasswordInput v ->
            model

        SignIn username password ->
            model



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input [ class "signin", type_ "submit", value "Signin", onClick <| SignIn (model.username) (model.password) ] []
        , input [ class "signin", type_ "password", placeholder "password", onInput PasswordInput, value model.password ] []
        , input [ class "signin", type_ "text", placeholder "username", onInput UserInput, value model.username ] []
        ]
```

**App Shell:**

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ header [] [ Login.view ??? ]
        ]
```

**Note:**
This is a common method of composing UX when using the Prism framework for WPF.

Comment: Just fyi: you can drop the attributes of the `SignIn` union type as the two strings are stored in your model. You can reach them in the update function without passing them in.

Comment: Example of an app doing what you want: https://github.com/rommsen/elm-bookkeeping/blob/master/src/elm/State.elm (look for the `Sub.map`, `Cmd.map`. And `Html.map` is used in the View.elm file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do for this is import it in your main module. Then add another top level message type for login messages, and add a case for it in your update function. The code looks like this...

```
import Login

type alias Model =
    { loginModel : Login.Model
    , (more stuff)
    }

type alias Msg
    = HandleLogin Login.Msg
    | (more stuff)

update msg model =
    case msg of
        HandleLogin subMsg ->
            let
                newState = Login.update subMsg model.loginState
             in
                 { model | loginState = newState }
         (more stuff)

 view model =
     div [] [
         Html.map HandleLogin <| Login.view model.loginState
     ]
```

Also don't forget the following in your login module

```
module Login exposing (..)
```

This wraps messages generated by the login view, then then passes them back into the login update function.

You can read more about Html.map [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#map)